# How to overlay two non-transparent images in Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a simple image manipulation function that applies a soviet flag filter to a profile picture. Both pictures are non-transparent. I have some code

```py
from PIL import Image

app = Flask(__name__)

img = Image.open("soviet.jpg")
back = Image.open("profile.jpg")

back.paste(img, (0, 0))
back.show()
```

That would work if either of the images were transparent. However, because my images are not transparent, it just shows the background. Also, the pictures have different resolutions, so it just shows the top left of the background. Is there a way to center & set the opacity of the profile picture, and then overlay it?

Comment: Try searching for image matting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to resize the images to match each other with the following:

```
back = back.resize(img.size)
```

then try using the [blend()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.blend) function:

```
blended_image = Image.blend(img, back, 0.5)
```

Comment: Any idea how to do it without resizing the images?